# Cannot gnerate dynamic JSP select using EL via Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring, jsp

I'm building a form which is dynamically create new input field using java script, but I'm facing a problem with the EL which is cannot be use inside the javascript to build the HTML page. below is the form that generate by the javascript.

[image]

int the controller is similar to this

```
List<LanguageEntity> languagelist = service.getAllLanguage();

session.setAttribute("languagelist", languagelist);
```

the jsp is similar to this

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>
                    <label>Field of Study:</label>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                id="exampleInputUser" placeholder="Field of Study:"
                                name="jp_entity.study_field">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <p class="help-block">The option is required!</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <p class="help-block">
                        <form:errors path="study_field"
                        cssClass="error"></form:errors>
                    </p>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </div>


        <div class="box-body dt-space">
            <div id="langid0"></div>
                <div style="text-align: right" onload="autoGenerate()">
                    <a id="addLang" href="">Add New</a>
                </div>

            </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                <dt>
                    <label>Sex:</label>
                </dt>
                <dd>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <select class="form-control" style="width: 150px;"
                                    name="jp_entity.sex">
                                <option value="1">Female</option>
                                <option value="2">Male</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <p class="help-block">The option is required!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </dd>
            </dl>
        </div>
```

and the javascript for generate the form is

```
        // Generate form language Skills
        $(document)
                .ready(
                        function() {
                            var num = 1;
                            $('#addLang')
                                    .unbind()
                                    .click(
                                            function() {
                                                var newNum = new Number(num);
                                                var newEle;
                                                newEle = $("<div class = 'row'></div>");
                                                newEle.attr('id', 'langid' + newNum)
                                                        .attr(
                                                                'name',
                                                                'ID' + newNum
                                                                        + '_reference');
                                                newEle.html("<div></div>");
                                                newEle
                                                        .html(""
                                                                + "<div class='col-md-12'>"
                                                                + "<div style='text-align:right'><a id='removeLang' onclick='"
                                                                + 'removeLang("langid'
                                                                + newNum
                                                                + '")'
                                                                + "'>Remove</a></div>"

                                                                + "<div class='form-group'>"
                                                                + "<dl class='dl-horizontal'>"
                                                                + "<dt>"
                                                                + "<label>Language Ability:</label>"
                                                                + "</dt>"
                                                                + "<dd>"
                                                                + "<div class='row'>"
                                                                + "<div class='col-md-8'>"
                                                                + "<div class='row'>"
                                                                + "<div class='col-md-6'>"
                                                                + "<label>Select Language:</label> <select"
                                                                + "class='form-control' name='lang_code'>"
                                                                + "<c:forEach items='${languagelist}' var='language'>"
                                                                + "<option value='${language.lang_code}'>${language.lang_name}</option>"
                                                                + "</c:forEach>"
                                                                + "</select>"
                                                                + "</div>"
                                                                + "<div class='col-md-6'>"
                                                                + "<label>Level:</label> <select class='form-control'"
                                                                + "name='level'>"
                                                                + "<option value='1'>Fluent</option>"
                                                                + "<option value='2'>Good</option>"
                                                                + "<option value='3'>Poor</option>"
                                                                + "</select>"
                                                                + "</div>"
                                                                + "</div>"
                                                                + "</div>"
                                                                + "</div>"
                                                                + "</dd>"
                                                                + "</dl>"
                                                                + "</div>"
                                                                +"");

                                                /*
                                                 * + "<div class='form-group'>" + "<dl class='dl-horizontal'>" + "<dt>" + "<label>Skill
                                                 * Name:</label>" + "</dt>" + "<dd>" + "<div
                                                 * class='row'>" + "<div
                                                 * class='col-md-8'>" + "<input
                                                 * type='text' class='form-control'" +
                                                 * "id='exampleInputUser'
                                                 * placeholder='Skill Name:'>" + "</div>" + "<div
                                                 * class='col-md-4'>" + "<p class='help-block'>The
                                                 * option is required!</p>" + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</dd>" + "</dl>" + "</div>" +
                                                 *  "<div class='form-group'>" + "<dl class='dl-horizontal'>" + "<dt>" + "<label>Experience
                                                 * Years:</label>" + "</dt>" + "<dd>" + "<div
                                                 * class='row'>" + "<div
                                                 * class='col-md-8'>" + "<input
                                                 * type='text' class='form-control'" +
                                                 * "id='exampleInputUser'
                                                 * placeholder='Experience Years:'>" + "</div>" + "<div
                                                 * class='col-md-4'>" + "<p class='help-block'>The
                                                 * option is required!</p>" + "</div>" + "</div>" + "</dd>" + "</dl>" + "</div>" + "</div>" +
                                                 * "");
                                                 */
                                                $('#langid0').before(newEle);
                                                $('#ID' + newNum + '_title').focus();
                                                num++;
                                                return false;

                                            });
                        });
```

and I have the bean class to store information of this section as following

```
    private Integer company_code;

    private Integer job_code;

    private Integer lang_code;

    private Integer level;
```

and the language class as following

```
private Integer lang_code;

@NotBlank
@Size(min = 0, max = 50)
private String lang_name;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date regist_date;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date update_date;

private Integer del_flag;
```

as you can see the select box cannot be generate using the EL via c:foreach at all, is there a better approach for this one? I don't mind using JSON or whatever solutions. And one more question, when submit the form how can I get all that objects in my controller? create a new class that wrap the array of that object or some other thing?

Answer (score 0):

JSTL is evaluted at server side. You cannot append jstl tags dynamically at client side and expect them to behave as you would.

You should be able to use the jstl code to control the js code getting passed to the client.

```
<c:forEach items='${languagelist}' var='language'>
$('<option>').val('${language.lang_code}').text('${language.lang_name}').appendTo('#idOfTheSelectTag');
</c:forEach>
```